# JSON file updating takes time

Tags: python, json, sockets

I want to transfer a JSON file between raspberry pi and a computer. I am using the socket module and sending JSON file in string format. Then I convert it to a dictionary and write it on a JSON file. but the problem is while updating the JSON file in a while loop, I get an error.

> File "", line 1
> {'locx': '10', 'temp1': '2', 'velox': '3'}{'locx': '15', 'temp1': '2', 'velox': '3'}
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

As far as I understand the refreshing is not fast and it appends new data to the old one. Is there any other way to transfer the JSON files or make the updating faster? or did I understand the problem correctly?

This is the code in the computer:

```
import socket

import json

import time

import ast

listensocket = socket.socket() #Creates an instance of socket

Port = 8000 #Port to host server on
maxConnections = 5

IP = '192.168.31.220'#socket.gethostname() IP address of local machine

listensocket.bind(('',Port))

#Starts server
listensocket.listen(maxConnections)
print("Server started at " + str(IP) + " on port " + str(Port))

#Accepts the incoming connection

(clientsocket, address) = listensocket.accept()
print("New connection made!")


dic=[]

while True:

    message = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode() #Gets the incoming message
    time.sleep(0.1)

    #message=json.loads(message)
    dictionary = ast.literal_eval(message)
    print(dictionary)
    with open("veri.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(dictionary,f)
```

I can write the code in raspberry too. if someone asks.

Comment: Missing a comma between the curly brackets. Perhaps Check what is sent out?

Comment: the problem is having 2 dictionaries in same file. i want to update the dictionary not a new one.

Comment: "in the same file"... what file is that? I see some socket calls. Something appears to have taken the string representation of 2 python dictionaries and concatentated them into a single string. That's a problem. A JSON encoded string and a newline between may be more reasonable. Do you control the thing that made the string? Then that's the first thing to fix.

Comment: Next you have to worry about the receive. There is no guarantee that you'll get the whole string on a single recv. You could write code that does receives and looks for newlines to split out individual JSON strongs.

Comment: By "file" i ment json. I get dictionaries which are converted to strings in order to recive them from raspberryi pi by using socket lib. But the iteration is fast and i cant use enough delay with time.sleep  because this recieving process must take like 0.3 seconds. My problem is updating the json file.  I use json.dump and when the while loop iterates, the code fills json with the new values that i just recieved form raspberry pi. But sometimes code fills json twice in a loop. Yes i get an invalid syntax error but the problem is this double filling.